# am trying to convert this for loop into list comprehension?

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, list-comprehension

```
L=[]
for i in range(11):
     L.append(1)
     for z in range(i):
        L.append(0)
L.append(1) #this is to add a 1 at the end of list
print(L)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should give the desired result - for `i` in the desired range, generate the tuple `(1,0,0,0...)` and then flatten the list of tuples. Finally, append the trailing `1`.

```
>>> [x for i in range(11) for x in (1,)+(0,)*i] + [1]
[1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Comment: You could make it a pure comprehension: `[x for i in range(-1,11) for x in (0,)*i+(1,)]`